# undefined value in perl condition

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

I am beginner in perl programming

I want to execute a portion of code when the value in the fetch is null means there is no cookie present and if there is a cookie then another portion.

But i am facing the error :

## Software error:

```
Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at /net/rtulmx0100/fs7/www/LabelMeDev_Student/annotationTools/perl/session_test.cgi line 93, <FP> line 3.
```

Here is my code :

```
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
$id = $cookies{'name'}->value;
if($id == null)
{ 
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n" ;
    print "hahahah";
}
else{
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n" ;
    print $id;
}
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It would have told you there's no such thing as `null`.

Comment: Also `==` tests for numeric equivalence. Since `null` is effectively the same as `"null"` and that numifies to `0`; you are effectively checking this: `$id == 0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no `null` in Perl, although there is an `undef`. You'd have gotten an error about using `null` if you were running with `use strict` turned on, which you should always do.

Since `CGI::Cookie` returns a list that be used to initialize a hash, we can use the [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) operator to see if a given key exists in the hash.

Also, since both branches of the condition result in printing a CGI header, we can move that outside the conditional, and we can use the standard [CGI](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER) module to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header( 'text/plain' );

my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
if ( exists $cookies{name} ) { 
    print $cookies{name}->value;
} else { 
    print "hahahah";
}
```

Comment: I think you should be testing `defined`, for both practical and pedagogical reasons.

Comment: @friedo thanks for the ellobrative answer.
One thing i want to ask you that i want to take the value from the global variable
 my $fullfn = $LM_HOME . "annotationTools/perl/session_location.txt";
where $LM_HOME is the global variable but the thing is that when i use my with $LM_HOME it becomes new variable but i need it to take the same value as global variable. So when using use strict it is giving the error.
I have include the file with global variable i.e require global.pm

Comment: @Zeeshan that is a different question, and should be asked on a new page. Also it is quite difficult to figure out what this new question is, so please improve it when you finally do ask. Include a statement of *why* you need to know it, so that we can provide better answers for your exact situation.